# recursive definition of the relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Give a recursive definition of the relation greater than on N X N using the successor operators s?

I answered this question throw this way:

Basis: o ∈ N X N
recursive step: if n ∈ N X N, then s(n) ∈ N X N

Can anyone plz help me out further with this question?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $R \subseteq \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ be our desired relation. Then here are some examples of elements that we want to belong to $R$:
\begin{align*}
&(1,0),\\
&(2,0),(2,1),\\
&(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),\\
&(4,0),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),\\
&~~~~~\vdots~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\ddots
\end{align*}

This suggests that our basis is that $(1,0) \in R$. For the recursive step, you should think about how to answer the following two questions:

- How do we get to the next row?
- How do we get to the next pair in a given row, without going too far?